# How can I write a for loop that creates a matrix of Euclidean distances between 50 different points? R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have created a matrix of 50 randomly generated (x,y) pairs, and I need to turn this into a matrix that displays the distance from any point (in the rows) to all the other points (in the columns).  This should result in diagonal 0s and be a *50* x *50* matrix.

I'll be calculating the distances using the formula: 
[image]

Creating the matrix of distances:

```
n = 50
x = round(runif(n)*1000)
y = round(runif(n)*1000)
coordinates = cbind(x,y)

head(coordinates)
       x   y
[1,] 266 478
[2,] 372 861
[3,] 573 438
[4,] 908 245
[5,] 202  71
[6,] 898  99
```

I've tried the following, but as you'll see from the `length(distances)` output, the number of elements in distances is not 2500 as I was expecting.  Also, the first element of distances is  445.4863 instead of 0 as I was hoping.

```
distances = c()
for (i in 1:n)
  for (j in 1:n)
    distances[i] = sqrt((coordinates[j,2]-coordinates[i,2])^2 + (coordinates[j,1]-coordinates[i,1])^2)

length(distances)     #This should be 2500 elements long
[1] 50           

distances = matrix(distances, nrow=n, ncol=n)
```

Comment: `as.matrix(dist(coordinates))`

Comment: This works flawlessly. I wasn't aware of the `dist()` function

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original code is that you save the calculated distance at each iteration to `distances[i]`. That means for every value of `i`, you overwrite the same position for each value of `j`. You could fix this by calculating an index that accounts for both `i` and `j`:

```
distances = c()
for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
        distances[(i - 1) * n + j] = sqrt((coordinates[j,2]-coordinates[i,2])^2 +
                                          (coordinates[j,1]-coordinates[i,1])^2)
    }
}
```

**But**, I wouldn't recommend this approach, as for loops in R are very slow when there are vectorized approaches available. At the very least, you should pre-allocate the distances vector using something like `distances = numeric(n * n)` because resizing a vector multiple times in R is particularly slow.